# Is there a way to reverse a windows update?

Tags: windows-7, bsod, windows-update, maintenance

The most recent Windows update has caused some issues with my system.   When I start up Starcraft, I get a BSOD (Blue Screen of Death).  I'd like to reverse the changes that Microsoft pushed out.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Control Panel > Uninstall a Program > View Installed Updates

You can uninstall whatever updates you want from there.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that may be easier is just to use System Restore to rollback the system to the state that it was in before your update was installed.

Comment: i wouldn't call a system restore "easier". I would actually call it more work and possibly more problematic of a way to rollback a system update.

Comment: +1 Rex use the control panel update uninstall.  In the future always use Custom update and look at the crap M.S. is putting on your system, some you don't need and others will cause problems like this.  If you do need the updates try them again and then check back after to see if there are others.  Also clean your system: Ccleaner (Reg)/ Disk/ Defrag ect and always back-up.